# Counting string features

Tags: python, string, curly-braces

The data is in a pandas dataframe from a csv. I brought it in like this:

```
listing = pd.read_csv("listings.csv")
```

I have an amenities column from an AirBnB data set. I am interested in when an AirBnB has 'pets allowed' as a part of their amenities.

```
in:   listing['amenities'].head(2)

out:  0     {TV,"Cable TV",Internet,Wifi,"Paid parking off...
      1     {TV,"Cable TV",Internet,Wifi,Kitchen,"Free par...
```

Often in the amenities column we will see `{TV,"Cable TV",Internet,Wifi,"Pets Allowed"...}`

How do I count the number of rows that have "Pets Allowed"?

I've tried:

```
pets_count = listing['amenities'].str.contains('pet*').sum()
pets_count
```

Which returns 59, but I know that this isn't the value because there are more than that.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: There's a lot of different answers to this depending on both the data type of the variables, and the encoding used. Please try to clarify further..

Comment: This looks like the text representation of a PostgreSQL array. Which format did the data set come in?

Comment: "I have an amenities column from an AirBnB data set." Show the code that you use to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to split the string by `,` and remove `"`

Like so :

```
s =  """{TV,"Cable TV",Internet,Wifi,Kitchen}"""
amenities = [amenitie.replace('"','').strip() for amenitie in s.replace('{', '').replace('}', '').split(',')]
if 'Pets allowed' in amenities:
  print('pets allowed !')
```